# viewing specific id from upload query

Tags: php, mysql

in my project there are 2 user, the admin uploading file into db stored in `tbl_upload`

**upload.php**

```
  if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) {
      $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(emp_id,file,ext,size)
      VALUES('$file_id','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
      mysql_query($sql);
```

and i already stored the id from `tbl_employee` and now my question is how can i view the specific id from view table

**view.php**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
```

this is where the files going `$folder="uploads/";` im thinking foreign key but i dont know where to start. please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last autoincremented ID using [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).
Filtering results by specific row (ID in your case) is done by WHERE clause.

```
$id_upload = mysql_insert_id();
$sql="SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id = ".(int)$id_upload." LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: its working but it views the last uploaded file. but if i want to view all uploaded file for the id?

Comment: For what ID? I thought you need for uploaded ID? If you need for employee ID, put the employee ID into the WHERE clause.

Comment: the tbl_upload is taking the emp_id from tbl_employee

Answer (score 0):

You need add column on tbl_uploads like this :

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_uploads
ADD COLUMN user_id
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
```

Also you can set Cascade properties to remove the files when the user is deleted.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_uploads
ADD COLUMN user_id
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But you need create a table with INNODB properties.

Also if you need get the last Id after insert PHP you can get it with mysql function on php

```
<?php
    $user_id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli("db_server", "db_user", "db_pass", "db_name");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connection error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    //remeber if the id field is auto_increment you don´t  need write on query
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_uploads (user_id, final_file,file_type,new_size) VALUES ('$user_id', '$final_file', '$file_type', '$new_size')";
    $mysqli->query($query);

    printf ("Last  id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);


    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: the tbl_employee is the table with INOODB